# Passing object as params to parent component in React does not work

Tags: reactjs, function, object, react-hooks, parent-child

I am making a movie review app. I have a Home component which renders card components and passes them the "movie" prop. The API call is inside of the Home component. Inside the card component I have a button which, on click, should send the movie prop to a different component called Watchlist. I get the error "handleAddToWatchlist is not a function". it is provided by the watchlist component and executed on click of the button. Please help.

Card component:

```
const Card = ({movie, handleAddToWatchList}) => {
    const { Title, Year, Actors, Genre, Image } = movie;

   
    const movieInfo = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(movie);
    }
    
    
    
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image">
                <img src={Image} alt="interstellar"/>
            </div>

            <div className="card-info">
                <h2 className="movie-title">{Title}</h2>
                <p className="movie-year">Year: {Year}</p>
                <p className="movie-genre">Genre: {Genre}</p>
                <p className="movie-actor">Actor: {Actors}</p>
            </div>




            <div className="movie-buttons">
                <button ><span class="material-symbols-outlined">star</span></button>
                <button onClick={() => handleAddToWatchList(movie)}><span className="material-symbols-outlined">add</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

)
}


export default Card;
```

Watchlist component:

```
const Watchlist = () => {
    const { watchlistData, setWatchlist } = useAppContext();

    const handleAddToWatchList = (movie) => {

        if (!watchlistData.some((item) => item.id === movie.imdbID)) {
            setWatchlist((prevData) => [...prevData, movie]);
          } else {
            console.log(`${movie.title} is already in the watchlist.`);
          }
    }



    return (
        <>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <Link to="/" style={linkStyle}> Log Out </Link> </li>
                <li> <Link to="/reviews" style={linkStyle}>My Reviews</Link>  </li>
                <li> <Link to="/home" style={linkStyle}> Home </Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div className="main-container">
        <div className="main">
            <div className="movie-container-with-filter">
                <div className="movie-container">
                    {watchlistData && watchlistData.length > 0 ? (

                        watchlistData.map((movie) => (
                             <Card
                             key={movie.imdbID}
                             movie={movie}
                             handleAddToWatchList={handleAddToWatchList}
                                  />
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <p>No movies in the watchlist</p>
                    )
                        
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div
)
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
    const [recordsPerPage] = useState(9)
    const [ searchfield, setSearchfield ] = useState('')
    const [dateFilter, setDateFilter] = useState(0);
    const [ selectedGenre, setSelectedGenre ] = useState("");

    const uniqueMovieIds = useRef(new Set());
    const apiKey = "apikey"

    const indexOfLastRecord = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstRecord = indexOfLastRecord - recordsPerPage

    const movieContainerRef = useRef(null)


    /*const fetchMovies = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=action&page=${currentPage}&apikey=${apiKey}&plot=full`)
            const data = await response.json()
            console.log(data);
        
            if (data.Response === 'True' && Array.isArray(data.Search)) {
                 // Filter out duplicates by IMDb ID
                 const uniqueMovies = data.Search.filter(newMovie => !uniqueMovieIds.current.has(newMovie.imdbID));
                
                 // Update the Set with new IMDb IDs
                 uniqueMovies.forEach(newMovie => uniqueMovieIds.current.add(newMovie.imdbID));
 
                 // SetMovies with the combination of existing movies and unique new movies
                 setMovies(prevMovies => [...prevMovies, ...uniqueMovies]);
                }
              
            
         else {
                console.error("Error fetching movies: ", data)
            } 
        }catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        }

    }*/

    const fetchMovies = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=action&page=${currentPage}&apikey=${apiKey}`);
          const data = await response.json();
      
          if (data.Response === 'True' && Array.isArray(data.Search)) {
            const detailedMovies = await Promise.all(
              data.Search.map(async (newMovie) => {
                const detailsResponse = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${newMovie.imdbID}&apikey=${apiKey}`);
                const detailsData = await detailsResponse.json();
                console.log(detailsData);
                return detailsData;
              })
            );
      
            setMovies(prevMovies => [...prevMovies, ...detailedMovies]);
          } else {
            console.error("Error fetching movies: ", data);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching data: ", error);
        }
      };

      //FILTERING

      const handleGenreFilter = (event) => {
        const selectedGenre = event.target.value;
        setSelectedGenre(selectedGenre)
      }

      const onSearchChange = (event) => {
        setCurrentPage(1);
        uniqueMovieIds.current.clear();
        setSearchfield(event.target.value);
      }

      const handleYearFilter = (event) => {
        const dateFilter = event.target.value;
        setDateFilter(dateFilter);
      }

      const applyFilters = () => {

        if(searchfield === "" || dateFilter === 0 || selectedGenre === "") {
            return movies
        }
        console.log("Year:", dateFilter);
        console.log("Genre:", selectedGenre);
        console.log("Search:", searchfield);
        let filteredMovies = movies;
        console.log("Movies: ", filteredMovies);

        if (searchfield !== "") {
            filteredMovies = filteredMovies.filter(movie => movie.Title.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()));
          }
          console.log("Fiultered by search: ",filteredMovies);
      
          if (dateFilter !== 0) {
            filteredMovies = filteredMovies.filter(movie => movie.Year == dateFilter);
          }
          console.log("Fiultered by date: ",filteredMovies);
      
          if (selectedGenre !== '') {
            const selectedGenresArray = selectedGenre.split(",").map(genre => genre.trim())

            filteredMovies = filteredMovies.filter(movie => {
                const movieGenresArray = movie.Genre.split(",").map(genre => genre.trim())
                return selectedGenresArray.some(selectedGenre => movieGenresArray.includes(selectedGenre))
            });
          }
      
          setMovies(filteredMovies);
          console.log("FilteredMovies",filteredMovies);
      }

      const handleFilterButtonClick = () => {
        applyFilters();
      }
    
      const handleResetButtonClick = () => {
        setSearchfield("");
        setDateFilter(0)
        setSelectedGenre("")
        

        applyFilters();
      }

    
    
    const loadMore = () => {
        setCurrentPage(prevPage => prevPage + 1);
        
        if (movieContainerRef.current) {
            const containerTop = movieContainerRef.current.offsetTop;

            if(window.innerWidth <= 600) {
                document.getElementById("mainContainer").scrollIntoView({
                    behavior:"smooth",
                });
            } else {

                movieContainerRef.current.scrollTo({
                    top: 0,
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                });
            }
        } 
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMovies()

    }, [currentPage])

    const handleAddToWatchList = () => {
        console.log("works");
    }


    return (
        <>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                
                <li className="nav-links-text"> <Link to="/" style={linkStyle}> Log Out </Link> </li>
                <li className="nav-links-text"> <Link to="/watchlist" style={linkStyle}>Watchlist </Link>  </li>
                {/*kad napravis usere, postavi path da bude "/:uid/watchlist"*/}
                <li className="nav-links-text"> <Link to="/reviews" style={linkStyle}> My Reviews </Link></li>

                <li className="title-home">mrabyEMIR</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div id="mainContainer" className="main-container">
        <div className="main">
            <div className="movie-container-with-filter">
                <div ref={movieContainerRef} className="movie-container">
                    <div className="movies">
                        {
                        
                        movies.slice(indexOfFirstRecord, indexOfLastRecord).map((movie) => {
                            
                            return <Card key={movie.imdbID}

                             movie={{
                                  
                                  Image:movie.Poster,
                                  Title:movie.Title,
                                  Year:movie.Year,
                                  Actors:movie.Actors,
                                  Genre:movie.Genre
                                    
                            }}
                            />
                        })
                
                    }
                    </div>
                    </div>

                <div className="movie-filter">
                    <label>Search</label>
                    <input onChange={onSearchChange} type="search" style={{color:"black"}}/>
                    <label>Year:</label>
                    <input type="number" style={{color:"black"}} onChange={handleYearFilter}/>


                    <label>Genre</label>
                    <select style={{color:"black"}} onChange={handleGenreFilter}>
                        <option value="">Select Genre</option>
                        <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
                        <option value="Western">Western</option>
                        <option value="Musical">Musical</option>
                        <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
                        <option value="Sci-Fi">Sci-Fi</option>
                        <option value="Action">Action</option>
                        <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
                    </select>

                    <button onClick={handleFilterButtonClick}>FILTER</button>
                    <input type="reset" id="reset" value={"RESET"} style={{color:"black"}} onClick={handleResetButtonClick}/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div className="load-more-container">
                    <button className="load-more" onClick={loadMore}>Next Page</button>
            </div>
                    
        </div>
        </>
    )
}



export default Home;
```

AppContext.js

```
const AppContext = createContext();

export function AppProvider({ children }) {
  const [watchlistData, setWatchlistData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ watchlistData, setWatchlistData }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <App/>
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I have tried everything and resorted to useAppContext even though I am very unfamiliar with react context.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Card` component, `handleAddToWatchList` is supposed to be passed to to `onClick` as so `onClick={handleAddToWatchList}` and in `Watchlist`, this is how you call the function `handleAddToWatchList={() => handleAddToWatchList(movie)}`

The bug occurs because `handleAddToWatchList` is a required prop in the `Card` component and it's not used in the `Home` component.

You can pass in an empty function to make `handleAddToWatchList` optional since it isn't used in the `Home` component.

```
const Card = ({movie, handleAddToWatchList}) => {
    const { Title, Year, Actors, Genre, Image } = movie;

   
    const movieInfo = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(movie);
    }
    
    
    
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image">
                <img src={Image} alt="interstellar"/>
            </div>

            <div className="card-info">
                <h2 className="movie-title">{Title}</h2>
                <p className="movie-year">Year: {Year}</p>
                <p className="movie-genre">Genre: {Genre}</p>
                <p className="movie-actor">Actor: {Actors}</p>
            </div>




            <div className="movie-buttons">
                <button ><span class="material-symbols-outlined">star</span></button>
                <button onClick={handleAddToWatchList}><span className="material-symbols-outlined">add</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

)
}


export default Card;
```

```
const Watchlist = () => {
    const { watchlistData, setWatchlist } = useAppContext();

    const handleAddToWatchList = (movie) => {

        if (!watchlistData.some((item) => item.id === movie.imdbID)) {
            setWatchlist((prevData) => [...prevData, movie]);
          } else {
            console.log(`${movie.title} is already in the watchlist.`);
          }
    }



    return (
        <>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <Link to="/" style={linkStyle}> Log Out </Link> </li>
                <li> <Link to="/reviews" style={linkStyle}>My Reviews</Link>  </li>
                <li> <Link to="/home" style={linkStyle}> Home </Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div className="main-container">
        <div className="main">
            <div className="movie-container-with-filter">
                <div className="movie-container">
                    {watchlistData && watchlistData.length > 0 ? (

                        watchlistData.map((movie) => (
                             <Card
                             key={movie.imdbID}
                             movie={movie}
                             handleAddToWatchList={() => handleAddToWatchList(movie)}
                                  />
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <p>No movies in the watchlist</p>
                    )
                        
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div
)
```

In your `Home` component, add `handleAddToWatchList={() => {}}` to your `Card` component as a prop

```
<Card 
  key={movie.imdbID}
  movie={{
       mage:movie.Poster,
       Title:movie.Title,
       Year:movie.Year,
       Actors:movie.Actors,
       Genre:movie.Genre
  }}
  handleAddToWatchList={() => {}}
/>
```

Comment: This helped partially, I discovered the issue. The Card Component takes in two parameters: "movie", and "handleAddToWatchlist". The Card component is called in both the Home and Watchlist component. Only the Watchlist component passes down the handleAddToWatchlist but not the Home component which is why the mistake was there. Still, I'm not sure how I might fix this

Comment: Can you update your question with the `Home` component? Let's see the data you are passing to both props

Comment: Updated. So the Home component doesnt contain the function which is meant to be passed down only by the watchlist component

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need to make `handleAddToWatchList` optional

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work. The function is not even ran and doesnt log out anything. I updated my question again with the context code

Comment: I've added an update. This time, make sure to follow every step. The bug occurs because `handleAddToWatchList` is a required prop in the `Card` component and it's not used in the `Home` component.

Comment: I did everything as you said but still nothing. I might try a different approach as this seems to be getting the better of me. Still the function is not even called.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured out the best way to go about this is to use React Context.
I set up two main states: mainMovies and watchlist, which can be accessible from anywhere.

AppContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AppContext = createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [mainMovies, setMainMovies] = useState([])
  const [watchlist, setWatchlist] = useState([]);


  const contextValue = {
    mainMovies,
    setMainMovies,
    watchlist,
    setWatchlist
  };


  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}

const useAppContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  if(!context) {
    throw new Error("useAppContext must be used within an AppProvider")
  }

  return context;
}

export { AppProvider, useAppContext}
```

Watchlist.js

```
const Watchlist = () => {
    const { watchlist } = useAppContext()

 
    return (
        <>
        
    <div className="main-container">
        <div className="main">
            <div className="movie-container-with-filter">
                <div className="movie-container">
                    <div className="movies">
                    {watchlist && watchlist.length > 0 ? (

                        watchlist.map((movie) => (
                             <Card
                             key={movie.imdbID}
                             movie={movie}
                             
                                  />
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <p>No movies in the watchlist</p>
                    )
                        
                    }
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

Card.js

```
const Card = ({movie}) => {
    const { Title, Year, Actors, Genre, Image } = movie;
    const { setWatchlist } = useAppContext();

   
    const handleAddToWatchList = () => {
        setWatchlist((prevWatchlist) => [...prevWatchlist, movie])
    }
    
    
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-image">
                <img src={Image} alt={Title}/>
            </div>

            <div className="card-info">
                <h2 className="movie-title">{Title}</h2>
                <p className="movie-year">Year: {Year}</p>
                <p className="movie-genre">Genre: {Genre}</p>
                <p className="movie-actor">Actor: {Actors}</p>
            </div>




            <div className="movie-buttons">
                <button ><span class="material-symbols-outlined">star</span></button>
                <button onClick={handleAddToWatchList}><span className="material-symbols-outlined">add</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

)
}
```

Thanks [X8inez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22931682/x8inez) for contributing to the thought process.